# Rendering partial views with Razor in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get a partial view to render using Razor in MVC5. When I use

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", model); }
```

I get the parser error:

> Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

When I remove the `{}`, i.e.:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", model);
```

I get the compilation error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You haven't posted the context of that code, but that error only really happens when you're using `@` directly within a code block without any HTML wrappings. For example:

```
@if (true) {
    @{ Html.RenderPartial(...); }
}
```

Would give you the error, while:

```
@if (true) {
    <div>
        @{ Html.RenderPartial(...); }
    </div>
}
```

Would be fine. You could also solve it by just removing the code block for `Html.RenderPartial` entirely, including the `@`:

```
@if (true) {
    Html.RenderPartial(...);
}
```

Comment: Well spotted, it was wrapped in a @foreach{}!

Comment: nice answer, detail was far better than mine :)

Answer (score 26):

You may also use `@Html.Partial("~/View/Home/myview.cshtml")`

It returns string while `Html.RenderPartial` calls Write internally, and returns void.

Comment: IMHO this is the correct/best answer to the question.

Answer (score 10):

This is wrong:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", model);
```

This is correct:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", model);  }
```

The parsing error might be caused by the partial view's content. For example, if you have an email address, make sure you use @@ to properly escape the @ sign.

> Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code
>   block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to
>   code.

Comment: it can also be because the code block (pact with the @ sing) is after and other code block (foreach if etc.) if this is the case you should not put an @ in front of the code block

Comment: @Believe2014 in my case, there is index view, i have create partial view search form i want to include in index view by   @{ Html.RenderPartial("TestOne");  }, if i run TestOne it self it's working but if i run index there is error , The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`.....

Answer (score 4):

can you show the code surrounding your RenderPartial? I'm guessing you're in a loop, if block, or some other type of code block. If so, you would just call

```
Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review your code, you might be getting that error because you are using this code:
`@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", model); }`
inside any other `@{}` clause. Please, read again carefully the error message you get in the browser, you don't need to use the `@{}` to switch to code because you already are inside, so, just remove `@{` and `}` and you should getting it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.Partial()`. It has three overloads, pass the parameters as per your requirement.